# Why I am getting unwanted select statements for the child entity even with the @OneToMany LAZY loading?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having three entities `Country`, `State`, `City`.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "country", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }) })
public class Country {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private int countryId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "phonecode", length = 45)
    private int phoneCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Set<State> states;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "state")
public class State {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "state_id")
    private int stateId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private Set<City> cities;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
public class City {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private int cityId;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45)
    private String name;

}
```

This is the relating in between them:
`Country` 1:N `State`
`State` 1:N `City`

I am using Spring framework, so for my DAO I am using `JpaRepository` for CRUD

```
public interface CountryDao extends JpaRepository<Country, Integer>{}
```

This the test case in which I trying to get all the cities of country having Id = 101

```
@Autowired
private CountryDao countryDao;

@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllStateWithCountryName() {
    Country country = countryDao.findById(101).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException());
    System.out.println("country: " + country.getName());
    country.getStates().forEach((state) -> System.out.println("state: " + state.getName()));
}
```

The test do bring me the cities data but I see some unwanted `select` statements generated for the `City` entity. I am quite surprised to see these as I have used `FetchType=LAZY` in `OneToMany` relation of `State` and `City` and I never called `state.getCities()`.

Any idea, what is the issue here?

This the output:

```
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country_1_12_0_, country0_.name as name2_12_0_, country0_.phonecode as phonecod3_12_0_ from country country0_ where country0_.country_id=?
country: India
Hibernate: select states0_.country_id as country_3_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_0_, states0_.state_id as state_id1_38_1_, states0_.name as name2_38_1_ from state states0_ where states0_.country_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
Hibernate: select cities0_.state_id as state_id3_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_0_, cities0_.city_id as city_id1_10_1_, cities0_.name as name2_10_1_ from city cities0_ where cities0_.state_id=?
state: Punjab
state: Lakshadweep
state: Kerala
state: Maharashtra
state: Himachal Pradesh
state: Madhya Pradesh
state: Natwar
state: Tamil Nadu
state: Gujarat
state: Uttarakhand
state: Delhi
state: Pondicherry
state: Haryana
state: Jammu and Kashmir
state: Rajasthan
state: Chandigarh
state: Sikkim
state: Arunachal Pradesh
state: Vaishali
state: Kenmore
state: Andhra Pradesh
state: Daman and Diu
state: Paschim Medinipur
state: Tripura
state: Chhattisgarh
state: Uttar Pradesh
state: Jharkhand
state: Manipur
state: Meghalaya
state: Andaman and Nicobar Islands
state: Mizoram
state: Goa
state: Karnataka
state: Dadra and Nagar Haveli
state: Odisha
state: West Bengal
state: Bihar
state: Assam
state: Narora
state: Nagaland
state: Telangana
```

Comment: Remove the `@Data` and try again. Probably the `toString` implemented by default from the `@Data` Lombok annotation is being called somewhere (during your debug, maybe) and calling all methods and triggering this SQLs.

Comment: To complete @Dherik's comment, you can keep `@Data` but review `@EqualsAndHashCode`. Beside that I aways found strange the fact that the first call to `country.getStates().` doesn't throw a `Lazy` exception. I have a similar case

Comment: @Dherik @akuma8 The culprit is `@EqualsAndHashCode` and not `@ToString`. More specifically it should be the `equals()` implementation by `@Data`, because it's the method which call probably the getters of all the fields.

Comment: @TheCoder, glad that you found the problem. Now I recommend to you to answer your own question, so the people that will have the same problem will found what you did to resolve the problem